# Visual Studio 2022 changes the solution file. How do I disable this?

Tags: visual-studio

I work on a team that uses Ryder.  I want to use Visual Studio 2022.

When I open the solution, Visual Studio makes a bunch of changes to the solution file (it modifies one of the project guids and adds debugging information for it).

I'm not allowed to check in these changes, nor are they needed, so every time I check anything in to git, I have to undo the changes to the solution file.

Is there any way to disable Visual Studio 2022 from doing this?

I've searched every setting I could think of and read the documentation but I can't find anything.  I don't want Visual Studio to change my solution file if I haven't added or removed projects.

Comment: gitignore? gitattributes? git’s content filters?

Comment: This is a complete pain in the proverbial for me too

Answer (score 1):

Though not exactly a "fix", I have a workaround that's been quite helpful from time to time. Copy the .sln file so you have a second one with a different filename. Let VS do what it wants to that second .sln without affecting the first one. You can take it one step further and gitignore the second file so that git will not constantly want to 'add' it to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find a solution for this.  I run a script every time I check in to undo the change to the solution file.

I am the only one on the team using Visual Studio and the team has strict rules about can be committed so this is the only solution.

It's not a problem now that I'm used to it, and I love Visual Studio 2022 so I'm willing to put up with it.